# python: edge attribute used as weight in networkx eigenvector_centrality

Tags: python, networkx, eigenvector

I created network from a csv file using:

```
adj_mat = np.loadtxt("outputsnet/output.csv",delimiter=',',skiprows=0)
net = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adj_mat, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

When I do:

```
w=net.edges(data=True)
print w
```

I get this as result:

```
[(51, 92, {'weight': 589.0}), (51, 95, {'weight': 579.0}), (53, 82, {'weight': 644.0}), (56, 83, {'weight': 644.0}), (58, 93, {'weight': 589.0}), (59, 84, {'weight': 644.0}), (62, 96, {'weight': 579.0}), (64, 97, {'weight': 579.0}), (65, 89, {'weight': 599.0}), (65, 98, {'weight': 579.0}), (66, 99, {'weight': 579.0})]
```

But when I try to compute eigenvector centrality by doing:

```
centrality = nx.eigenvector_centrality(net,weight='weight')
print(['%s %0.2f'%(node,centrality[node]) for node in centrality])
```

I find all weights equal to 0 as I didn't define weight  parameters :

```
['64 0.00', '65 0.00', '66 0.00', '99 0.00', '51 0.00', '97 0.00', '96 0.00', '98 0.00', '82 0.00', '83 0.00', '84 0.00', '53 0.00', '56 0.00', '89 0.00', '58 0.00', '59 0.00', '92 0.00', '93 0.00', '62 0.00', '95 0.00']
```

Can you help me to define the edge attribute used as weight in my example ?

Comment: What version of networkx are you using (`networkx.__version__`)? When I try this with your data, `nx.eigenvector_centrality` fails to converge.